# "unexpected end of JSON input" when an array of objects is passed in POST request

Tags: go, go-gin

```
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func Receive(c *gin.Context) {
  // Gets JSON ecnoded data
  rawData, err := c.GetRawData()
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }

  logger.Info("Raw data received - ", rawData)
}
```

This code snippet works when I pass a Json object `{"key":"value"}` but gives an error:

> "unexpected end of JSON input"

when I pass an array like `[{"key":"val"},{"key": "val"}]` as the input.

Comment: [`GetRawData`](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/context.go#L734) doesn't do anything with json, it just reads the request's body, so that error that you quoted must come from code that you haven't shared.

Comment: Im sending the requests via Postman, using 'Raw' option under body

Comment: Is it set to `JSON (application/json)`?

Comment: @Neville what I'm trying to say is that `GetRawData` can't possibly return the error `unexpected end of JSON input` (unless you're using some other version of gin), that error is returned by `encoding/json`'s decoder, which is never touched by `GetRawData`. So the handler code you've shared is irrelevant to the problem you have, the error is coming from somewhere else. Whether its a problem with Postman, or gin attempting to do some magic, or some middleware you may be using, I don't know however `GetRawData` it is *not*.

Comment: @mkopriva - Apologies, the problem occurred when I was doing a json.Unmarshall. Its solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All GetRawData() does](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/context.go#L734) is return stream data, so that shouldn't cause your error:

```
// GetRawData return stream data.
func (c *Context) GetRawData() ([]byte, error) {
    return ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
}
```

However, try using `BindJSON` and deserialise into a struct. See for example [this question](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/715).

```
type List struct {
    Messages []string `key:"required"`
}

func Receive(c *gin.Context) {
    data := new(List)
    err := c.BindJSON(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```